# How to read certain words from a line and store them in different variables in bash script?

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash, shell

I want to read the output from the following command and store certain words from that lines to certain variables:

`ps -eaf |grep mongod`

**Output**:

```
root     12911     1  7 16:59 ?        00:05:48 /home/mongo/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet mongoReplica --port 27017 --dbpath /home/mongo/data/db/rs0-1 --oplogSize 700
root     22259  7895  0 18:16 pts/4    00:00:00 grep mongod
```

Here, "12911" is the PID, "/home/mongo/..." is the CMD.
I want to write an if condition (or a for loop too?) here to read that

- If there is "--port 27017" in the line, then store its PID, "12911" in a variable
- And store "/home/mongo/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet mongoReplica --port 27017 --dbpath /home/mongo/data/db/rs0-1 --oplogSize 700" in another variable,
- And store "/home/mongo/data/db/rs0-1" in another variable.

This is what I have so far:

```
ps -eaf | grep mongod | while read -r pid cmd; do
    echo "pid: $pid, cmd: $cmd"
done
```

Current Output:

```
pid: root, cmd: 12911     1  6 16:59 ?        00:05:56 /home/mongo/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet mongoReplica --port 27017 --dbpath /home/mongo/data/db/rs0-1 --oplogSize 700
pid: root, cmd: 24862 24860  0 18:29 pts/4    00:00:00 grep mongod
```

Comment: default behavior is for `read` to use white space to delimit fields which means `pid` gets the first field (`root`) and `cmd` gets the rest of the line; you can add more variables (eg, `read -r user pid ppid ...` to break up the `ps` output into more variables; since `ps` output formats can vary (thus leading to parsing issues), I'd probably want to play with the `ps -o` option to format the output in a consistent format that will make your coding easier (ie, only display what you want and in an easily parsable format)

Comment: @markp-fuso and how would i write the if condition here to make sure that I only read the line which has "--port 27017"

Comment: pipe the ps output to grep; grep for port and 27017; pipe the grep output to the `while read` loop

Comment: @markp-fuso can you help me with that by typing it out? I'd really appreciate it. never wrote a bash before so no idea what it means

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions and collection of OP's comments:

- there may be more than one `mongod` process (per OP's use of a `while` loop)
- parsed data needs to be stored in variables for use in follow-on scripting (per OP's comments)
- OP's `ps` command allows for formatting of output

Since `ps` output can vary widely across different *nix implementations I'll start by having `ps` output what we need, eg:

```
ps -eo pid,cmd         # list all processes, only display the pid and command
```

We can then pipe this to a `grep` command to pull out only the line(s) of interest (ie, contains `mongod` and `--port 27017`:

```
ps -eo pid,cmd | grep -- '[m]ongod .*--port 27017`
```

**NOTE**: placing the `m` in brackets should eliminate the `ps` output record for the `grep` command (ie, should not need to run `grep -v grep` to skip a `grep` line)

To show how this answer deals with multiple `mongod` processes I'm working with two sets of `ps` output (formatted as `-o pid,cmd`):

```
12911 /home/mongo/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet mongoReplica --port 27017 --dbpath /home/mongo/data/db/rs0-1 --oplogSize 700
23952 /home/mongo/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet mongoReplica --port 27017 --dbpath /home/mongo/data/db/rs0-2 --oplogSize 700
```

To allow for the parsed data to be available to follow-on processing we'll need to modify the `while` loop structure to ensure we do not store the parsed data with in a sub-process call.  This means:

```
# we replace this:

ps ... | grep ... | while read -r ...

# with this:

while read -r ... ; done < <(ps ... | grep ...)
```

Pulling this all of this together we have:

```
unset pids cmds dbpaths                  # make sure nothing in our array variables

i=1                                      # initialize our array index

while read -r pid cmd
do
    pids[i]="${pid}"                     # store current pid
    cmds[i]="${cmd}"                     # store current cmd

    dbpath="${cmd##*--dbpath[ =]}"
    dbpaths[i]="${dbpath%% *}"           # store current dbpath

    ((i++))                              # increment the array index for next pass through the loop
done < <(ps -eo pid,cmd | grep -- '[m]ongod .*--port 27017')

# at this point we've finished parsing the 'ps' output and follow-on
# processing can access this data via the 3x arrays, eg;

for (( i=1 ; i<=${#pids[@]} ; i++ ))
do
    echo "++++++++++++++++ dataset # ${i}"
    echo "pid:    ${pids[i]}"
    echo "cmd:    ${cmds[i]}"
    echo "dbpath: ${dbpaths[i]}"
done

echo "++++++++++++++++"
```

This generates:

```
++++++++++++++++ dataset # 1
pid:    12911
cmd:    /home/mongo/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet mongoReplica --port 27017 --dbpath /home/mongo/data/db/rs0-1 --oplogSize 700
dbpath: /home/mongo/data/db/rs0-1
++++++++++++++++ dataset # 2
pid:    23952
cmd:    /home/mongo/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --replSet mongoReplica --port 27017 --dbpath /home/mongo/data/db/rs0-2 --oplogSize 700
dbpath: /home/mongo/data/db/rs0-2
++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: One of the perils of parsing `ps` is that this is always system-dependent. I'm guessing you are using Linux options and conventions here, too.

Comment: I added `tr -s ' '` to my own script to normalize the spaces between command-line parameters; you sometimes see multiple spaces there. On the whole, I would switch to Awk over `grep` + `while read -r`

Comment: sure, there are a handful of ways to slice-n-dice this ... some better than others ... but without more details from OP (eg, multiple `mongod` processes? need to use parsed data after leaving the loop? etc), we're left with (lots of) guessing ... and, I'm not sure about you, but I don't want to spend a couple hours writing an answer that covers all possible scenarios :-)

Comment: Maybe `ps -eo pid,cmd | awk '/[m]ongod .*--port 27017/ { pid=$1; cmdline=substr($0, length($1)+1); dbpath=cmdline; gsub(/.* --dbpath[= ]/, "", dbpath); gsub(/ .*/, "", dbpath); print pid, dbpath, cmdline }`

Comment: @markp-fuso this looks like a very good solution but I keep getting two errors:
    line 16: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
    line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer  try it again, had a back quote instead of a normal quote (at the end of the `ps|grep`)

Comment: @markp-fuso It worked very well! But I want to be able to use those variables outside of the while + read loop. I need to use the pid to kill the process and dbpath to remove the files from there. I cannot seem to use those 3 variables outside of the loop - i tried printing them but they don't print.

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer one more try ... assuming there may be more than one `mongod` process I've opted to store the parsed data in arrays; the contents of these arrays should be available outside of the `while` loop

Comment: @markp-fuso this worked very well. A quick questtion, How would I write a condition after killing the processes that are running on port 27017 to make sure that there no processes that are running on port 27017? I need to print out "All processes killed" by verifying that no process is running on port 27017.

Comment: `netstat`?  a google search on `linux list ports in use` brings up quite a few hits that may be of use

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux, a more robust solution is to examine the machine-readable information in the `/proc` filesystem.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for pid in $(pidof mongod); do
  cmdline=$(tr -s '\0' ' ' </proc/$pid/cmdline)
  if grep -Fe '--port 27017' <<<"$cmdline"; then
    dbpath=${cmdline##*--dbpath[ =]}
    dbpath=${dbpath%% *}
    printf '%s\n' 'We can haz successfullitudity!' \
         "PID: $pid" "DB path: $dbpath" "Full command line: $cmdline"
  fi
done
```

There could be multiple `mongod` instances; you'll have to figure out what to do in that case separately.

In brief, `pidof cmd` gets the PIDs for all processes running `cmd`; we then examine the information about each returned process ID in `/proc`. For example, the current working directory of process 1234 is `/proc/1234/cwd` and the command line used to start the process is in `/proc/1234/cmdline`. We `grep` the command line for the `--port` option, and if that's successful, we also parse out the `--dbpath` using a simple chained [parameter expansion.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

This is not a complete script; you'd have to continue it to actually do something with the variables we defined. Once the script has finished, the variables will not be available any longer.

This is still somewhat brittle; for example, if `mongod` provides several aliases for the same option name, you would have to parse the command line until you find one of the aliases for the option you want.

Comment: when I echo dbpath, it doesn't print anything. could you fix that please? thank you!!

Comment: A complication is that the data in `/proc` is null-terminated which is slightly tricky to handle in shell script. Updated again; hope this finally works for you.